# Using client certificates in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, rest, https, certificate

we are building a React UI platform website. We need to call a third party RESTFul service which requires us to attached a client certificate for authentication in the RESTful requsts. We can't find a solution in React to do this - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Unfortunately questions that are primarily seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more, are off-topic. Please edit your question as to show what you have already attempted

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would need to write piece of code to handle, since its browser based request, accepting a certs in web browser will be sufficient.

There are couple of ways to have the certificate enabled from your browser,

1. Access the Rest API Endpoint(https) in web browser, when you open first time, bowser will ask you to select the certificate, choose the right one and accept it. the rest will be handled by your web browser. whenever application/website request the data from https endpoints browser will serve the already accepted certificate.
2. open the website in which you consume Https endpoints, prior to making a request browser will ask you to accept the certs on the first time, upon accepting the certs browser will serve the certs for every requests.